# Смена содержимого div'а через промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Новости должны меняться каждые 5 секунд.

```
function NewsRotator() {
    var count_news = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < count_news; i++) {
        if ($('.news-' + i).is(':visible')) {
            $('.news-' + i).css('display', 'none');
            $('#button-0').removeClass("active");
            if (i < (count_news - 1)) {
                var j = i + 1;
                $('.news-' + j).css('display', 'block');
                $('#button-' + j).addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                $('.news-0').css('display', 'block');
                $('#button-0').addClass("active");
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(NewsRotator(), 3000);
});
```

Код работает, но вызывается только один раз в самом начале. Если заменить `setInterval` на `setTimeout` и занести его в тело, то тоже вызывается 1 раз, но идет переполнение стека. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо изменить

```
setInterval(NewsRotator(), 3000);
```

на

```
setInterval(NewsRotator, 3000);
```

потому что `setInterval` хочет функцию, а не хочет значение, которое функция возвращает.

Кстати, если хотите, чтобы новости менялись каждые 5 секунд, надо изменить `3000` на `5000`.

Вот живой пример похожей функции:

```js
var newsIndex = 1;
function NewsRotator() {
  $(".news").hide();
  $(".news" + newsIndex).show();
  
  var newsCount = 5;
  newsIndex++;
  if(newsIndex > newsCount) {
    newsIndex = 1;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  NewsRotator();
  setInterval(NewsRotator, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news news1">Новости 1</div>
<div class="news news2">Новости 2</div>
<div class="news news3">Новости 3</div>
<div class="news news4">Новости 4</div>
<div class="news news5">Новости 5</div>
```

Comment: все равно выполняется лишь раз

Comment: @Vadim.K функция выполняется каждые 3 (5) секунд. [Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4h8odx0n/). А вот то, что вы нахимичили в теле самой функции - это уже другой вопрос. Например, `break` в конце тела `for`, изничтожающий весь смысл цикла (после первой же итерации цикл стопорится).

Comment: сорри, этот break все и валит, его нужно на уровень выше. Спасибо